# Is there such a word as 'untabulated'?

Tags: vocabulary

In writing my dissertation, I want to describe that I have repeated the analysis using slightly different measures as a robustness check, but i did not report the results in text and hence what is the word to use.

The results **(untabulated/unreported)** show that group A remains to perform well.

Should i use untabulated, unreported or otherwise?

Comment: *Unreported* means you don't have the numbers, or you didn't include them in any reports and haven't otherwise made them available.  *Untabulated* means you have them but have not included them in your tables or computations.

Comment: When you repeated the analysis, did you arrange the resulting data in tabular form? If not, the data is untabulated. If so, but you have not reported the results, the data is unreported, but you are reporting a summary of the tabulated results with the example sentence, so calling it unreported is not right. Instead, you might say "The tabulated results [of the analysis] show etc."

Comment: @HotLicks Or indeed (as I read it) that you haven't formatted the data using tab indents. If that can somehow be made to make sense in the context given.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Yes, "(un)tabulated" can mean several different things, depending on context.

Comment: (But, eg, if one were hearing election reports on the radio, one might hear "the ballots from the 7th ward have not yet been tabulated", meaning that the ballots have not been counted and those counts added to the running total yet.)

Comment: @HotLicks so there is such a word as 'untabulated'? Because i can't seem to find this word in the oxford dictionary.

Comment: "un-" is a bog-standard prefix that can be used to modify essentially any garden-variety adjective.

Answer (score 2):

**Tabulate** [means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tabulate):

> to arrange information in an organized way so that it can be studied,
>   recorded, etc.

"Tabulated" is (in the sense we're interested in here) treated as an adjective, meaning having been arranged as above.

"Untabulated" is simply "tabulated" with the "un-" prefix added.  "Un-" simply means "not", so "untabulated" means "not tabulated".  "Un-" may be used with pretty much any adjective, so the fact that "untabulated" isn't found in a dictionary is not a matter of concern.

"Unreported" might also be used, but one wonders if you don't mean simply "not shown here", which is not precisely what either word means.

It seems to me that you should perhaps use plain words to describe the situation, vs trying to find the "perfect" hair-splitting word.  Eg, "As a test of the robustness of the results I have performed an analysis of a similar yet different set of data (and received essentially the same results), but I have not included those details in this report."

Answer (score -1):

For me, untabulated means the data are shown as flat. i.e. they are not cross-tabulated into square form. So flat data have multiple index fields and a new row is created whenever one of those index field changes value and you have data fields associated with each combination of indices. Tabulated data has one of those index fields against another and a data value for their intersection. This is two dimensional but you could do it in more.